# Is there a way to turn off specific built-in tokenization rules in Spacy?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, spacy

Spacy automatically tokenizes word contractions such as "dont" and "don't" into "do" and "nt"/"n't".  For instance, a sentence like "I dont understand" would be tokenized into: **["I", "do", "nt", "understand"]**.

I understand this is usually helpful in many NLP tasks, but is there a way to suppress this [special tokenization rule in Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#tokenization) such that the result is **["I", "dont", "understand"]** instead?

This is because I am trying to evaluate the performance (f1-score for BIO tagging scheme) of my custom Spacy NER model, and the mismatch in the number of tokens in the input sentence and the number of predicated token tags is causing problems for my evaluation code down the line:

- Input (3 tokens): **[("I", "O"), ("dont", "O"), ("understand", "O")]**
- Predicted (4 tokens): **[("I", "O"), ("do", "O"), ("nt", "O"), ("understand", "O")]**

Of course, if anyone has any suggestions for a better way to perform evaluation on sequential tagging tasks in Spacy (perhaps like the [seqeval](https://github.com/chakki-works/seqeval) package but more compatible with Spacy's token format), that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: If you need a whitespace tokenizer, see https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer-example

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the comment. I did consider this while looking for a potential solution but I didn't try it straight away because it wouldn't get rid of trailing punctuation like commas and full stops. Gave it a shot after seeing your comment and turns out this is good enough a solution for my issue where I realised that trailing punctuation was already dealt with in the processed input data. 

Out of curiosity, is there no way to selectively deactivate a few special case tokenization rules apart from making your own custom tokenizer and re-implementing only the desired rules?

Answer (score 5):

The special-case tokenization rules are defined in the [`tokenizer_exceptions.py`](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/tokenizer_exceptions.py) in the respective language data ([see here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/0c74506c9cb79c76ca06ef04a4d44a042e1b3f7c/spacy/lang/en/tokenizer_exceptions.py#L225) for the English "nt" contractions). When you create a [new `Tokenizer`](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#init), those special case rules can be passed in via the `rules` argument.

### Approach 1: Custom tokenizer with different special case rules

So one thing you could do for your use case is to reconstruct the English `Tokenizer` with the same prefix, suffix and infix rules, but with only a filtered set of tokenizer exceptions. Tokenizer exceptions are keyed by the string, so you could remove the entries for `"dont"` and whatever else you need. However, the code is quite verbose, since you're reconstructing the whole tokenizer:

```py
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.lang.punctuation import TOKENIZER_PREFIXES, TOKENIZER_SUFFIXES, TOKENIZER_INFIXES                                                                          
from spacy.lang.en import TOKENIZER_EXCEPTIONS  
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_suffix_regex, compile_infix_regex

prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(TOKENIZER_PREFIXES).search
suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(TOKENIZER_SUFFIXES).search
infix_re = compile_infix_regex(TOKENIZER_INFIXES).finditer
filtered_exc = {key: value for key, value in TOKENIZER_EXCEPTIONS.items() if key not in ["dont"]} 

nlp = English()
tokenizer = Tokenizer(
    nlp.vocab, 
    prefix_search=prefix_re, 
    suffix_search=suffix_re, 
    infix_finditer=infix_re, 
    rules=filtered_exc
)
nlp.tokenizer = tokenizer
doc = nlp("I dont understand")
```

### Approach 2: Merge (or split) tokens afterwards

An alternative aproach would be to keep the tokenization as it is, but add rules on top that *merge* certain tokens back together aftwards to match the desired tokenization. This is obviously going to be slower at runtime, but it might be easier to implement and reason about, because you can approach it from the perspective of "Which tokens are currently separated but should be one?". For this, you could use the [rule-based `Matcher`](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching) and the [retokenizer](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#retokenization) to merge the matched tokens back together. As of spaCy v2.1, it also supports splitting, in case that's relevant.

```py
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = English()
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
patterns = [[{"LOWER": "do"}, {"LOWER": "nt"}]]
matcher.add("TO_MERGE", None, *patterns)

doc = nlp("I dont understand")
matches = matcher(doc)
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = doc[start:end]
        retokenizer.merge(span)
```

The above pattern would match two tokens (one dict per token), whose lowercase forms are "do" and "nt" (e.g. "DONT", "dont", "DoNt"). You can add more lists of dicts to the patterns to describe other sequences of tokens. For each match, you can then create a `Span` and merge it into one token. To make this logic more elegant, you could also wrap it as a [custom pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components), so it's applied automatically when you call `nlp` on a text.